# Validation errors are not passed as props in Inertia-vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am doing a simple register form, using the existing register logic of AuthController@register

The request hits the controller successfully, but when I viewed validation errors in console log,showed
"[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: errors is not defined"

this is my vue code

```
<script>
  export default {
props:{errors:Object},
    name:"Register",
    data(){
      return {
        name:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        image:"",
      };
    },
    methods:{
      selectimage(e){
       this.image=e.target.files[0];
       
      
      },
      register(){
        
        var data=new FormData();
        data.append('name',this.name);
        data.append('email',this.email);
        data.append('password',this.password);
        data.append('image',this.image);
        this.$inertia.post('/register',data);
console.log(errors.name);
      },
    },
   
  };
  </script>
```

And this is html form

```
        <form @submit.prevent="register">
       {{form}}
         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control border border-danger" id="name" v-model="name">
     <small class="text text-danger">Please Enter</small>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" v-model="email">
         </div>
   <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password">password</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="password">
         </div>
  <div class="form-group">
         <label for="image">choose image</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" @change="selectimage">
         </div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right">submit</button>
          </form>
```

this is controller

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
   {
   
    $request->validate([
     'name'=>'required',
    'email'=>'required',
    'password'=>'required|min:8',
     'image'=>'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
]);

   }
```

Comment: Where are your errors passed to the inertia file to be shared with Vue? Typically, this is defined in `HandleInertiaMiddleware`.

Comment: Problem solved
I forgot to install inertia:middleware
Thank you